# How to Set up Contacts in Marketing Cloud to populate records from Personalization Builder Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, contactbuilder, einstein-recommendations

I worked on Personalization Builder and collected data about users based on collection codes set up on a demo webpage.
The data is in the Standard Personalization Builder Data Extension.
IGO_PROFILES

[image]

These users are not in the list of my All Contacts in Contact Builder. What can I do to set up that contact records are created for these users or any other new user on the website.
thanks

Comment: Once you send to them, they will be added to contacts

Answer (score 0):

Adding these as contacts is IMHO not needed for any use case. Normally I would just use PI and IGO tables as source for query activities segmenting my consumers based on their browsing behaviour. To achieve this, they don't need to be in SFMC as contacts. Also, I will strongly recommend AGAINST using email addresses in `setUserInfo` call. Instead you should used a more anonymised identifier - eg. hashed email address - as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_set_user_info.htm&type=5) and here: [Collect.js Predictive Intelligence Set User Info Email Value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297841/collect-js-predictive-intelligence-set-user-info-email-value)